slurm - minimizing effect of offline CPUs
I am doing experiments seeing how slurm behaves when it finds offline CPUs. In my experiments, slurm provides configurations that make available too few CPUs. Here's a few examples from an 8-cpu node I have been using for testing.
When I run slurm -C on the node with all CPUs online I get:
CPUs=8 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=2 ThreadsPerCore=2
When I offlined only one of the CPUs (cpu3), I get:
CPUs=7 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=2 ThreadsPerCore=1
The problems begin here. If you provide that configuration in slurm.conf keeping Procs=7, slurm will complain and will end up with an unusable node (ÌNVALID_REG I think is shown in State of the node). So Procs can be avoided altogether and I end up with only 4 CPUs available.
If I shutdown at this point the other thread in the same core of the thread I disabled before (cpu2), I get:
CPUs=6 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=1 ThreadsPerCore=2
So now slurm is very happy to go back to using 2 threads per socket (because all active cores have 2 threads active) but now only a single core from each socket is available.... we end up, again, with only 4 usable CPUs, according to slurm.
This next step was the killer for me. By disabling one more thread from any of the remaining active cores, we end up with this (I set all CPUs to be online again and then offlined cpu0, cpu1 which are in the same core and also cpu6 for this one):
CPUs=5 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=1 ThreadsPerCore=1
Which would make only 2 CPUs available, from just having 3 CPUs offline.
Are there ways to make as more CPUs available to slurm as possible in these scenarios?

Seems like the values that slurm is providing in slurm -C are coming from lscpu so I will make a new question that is related to how lscpu (and perhaps the kernel?) behaves instead of being related to slurm.
